# How to add two (or more) AJS.MultiSelect fields of the same type on the page

Tags: plugins, jira

Jira 7.12.
My add-on adds a "AJS.MultiSelect" type field. Then I create two different fields of this type.     But I can't add them both on the form. One of them only works.

```
JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function (e, context) {
    var elems = AJS.$('select[name^=departments-field-customfield_]');        
    for (el in elems) {
        var     departmentsField = new AJS.MultiSelect({                
            element: el,               
            itemAttrDisplayed: "title",
        });
    }

//    var   myField = new AJS.MultiSelect({    //it works with one field
//        element: AJS.$('#departments-field'),  
//        itemAttrDisplayed: "title",
//    });

});
```

vm:

```
##disable_html_escaping()
#set($i18nprefix = "departments-field-$customField.id")

<div class="field-group">
    <label for="departments-field-$customField.id">$customField.name</label>
    <select class="multi-select" size="5" id="departments-field-$customField.id" name="departments-field-$customField.id" multiple>
        #foreach($department in $departments)
            #set($selected = false)
            #if($selectedDepartments.contains($department))
                #set($selected = true)
            #end
            <option#if($selected) selected="selected"#end title="${department.name()}" value="${department.unique1CCode()}">${department.driftedCodeName()}</option>
        #end
    </select>
    <!--<span class="aui-form">&nbsp;<a href="#" id="departments-field-select-all">Select All</a></span>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault. My  elements have the same ids.